# Create vswitches pn ESXI for PFsense

Tags: virtualization, firewall, vmware-esxi, pfsense, network-design

iam trying to build a new network infrastructure on the new blace 
and i have:

- 3 ISP WAN Links
- one dedicated server with one Lan card
- One cisco Managed switch - SF200 Model
- server for ERP system

so i decided to use ESXI on the server and use it to create DC and Firewall - PFsense then i designed my network to work on three different Vlans

- Vlan 10 - for WAN Links and use them as Load Balance by the firewall
- Vlan 20 - for employee users 10.10.10.x /24
- Vlan 30 - for Guest users 10.10.50.x /24

so i created the three vlans on cisco switch but iam facing problem to create the vswitchs and network cards on esxi for the pfsense any suggesting for how many network cards i should use on the firewall VM and how to design them like which one should connect to the physical card and which cards should connect to separated vswitch thank you in advanced for any help

Answer (score 0):

I would say to set up 5 interfaces on the PFSense firewall: one for each of your WAN links, one for VLAN 20 and one for VLAN 30. You should, however, separate the 3 WAN links into 3 different VLANs unless they are on the same subnet with the same ISP.

Next, trunk the port on your physical server to the Cisco switch to pass the tags and have access ports for each of the 3 WAN links that correspond to their VLAN id. I've done this before in a lab, but it's not really secure.